# Error to load a pre-trained BERT model

Tags: python, nlp, bert, transformer

### Background

I'm reading [this article](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2020/12/ner-with-little-data-transformers-to-the-rescue/) about a natural language task, named entity recognition and trying to load a pre-trained BERT model on Google colaboratory.

**How can I fix an error to load a pre-trained BERT model?**

### Code

```py
from transformers import AutoConfig, TFAutoModelForTokenClassification
MODEL_NAME = 'bert-base-german-cased' 
config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME, num_labels=len(schema))
model = TFAutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME, config=config)
model.summary()
```

### Error

I can understand that schema is not defined before the line, but I cannot find a clew on the article to fix it.

```
      1 from transformers import AutoConfig, TFAutoModelForTokenClassification
      2 MODEL_NAME = 'bert-base-german-cased'
----> 3 config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME, num_labels=len(schema))
      4 model = TFAutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME, config=config)
      5 model.summary()

NameError: name 'schema' is not defined
```

### What I tried

I checked [previous blogpost](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2020/11/take-control-of-named-entity-recognition-with-you-own-keras-model/) following the advice from a comment, and found one description.

However, I'm not sure where to insert it to the original code.

```
For simplicity, we’ll truncate the sentences to a maximum length and pad shorter input sequences. But first, let us determine the set of all tags in the data and add an extra tag for the padding:

#code
schema = ['_'] + sorted({tag for sentence in samples for _, tag in sentence})
```

Is it correct understanding?

```
def load_data(filename: str):
   with open(filename, 'r') as file:
     lines = [line[:-1].split() for line in file]
     samples, start = [], 0
     for end, parts in enumerate(lines):
       if not parts:
         sample = [(token, tag.split('-')[-1]) for token, tag in lines[start:end]]
         samples.append(sample)
         start = end + 1
     if start < end:
       samples.append(lines[start:end])
     
     return samples

samples = load_data('data/01_raw/bag.conll')
train_samples = load_data('data/01_raw/bag.conll')
val_samples = load_data('data/01_raw/bgh.conll')
all_samples = train_samples + val_samples

schema = ['_'] + sorted({tag for sentence in samples for _, tag in sentence})
```

I checked the output.

```
print(schema)
#result
['_', 'AN', 'EUN', 'GRT', 'GS', 'INN', 'LD', 'LDS', 'LIT', 'MRK', 'O', 'ORG', 'PER', 'RR', 'RS', 'ST', 'STR', 'UN', 'VO', 'VS', 'VT']
```

Comment: You have to define the number of classes yourself, see also what the value means in their [previous blogpost](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2020/11/take-control-of-named-entity-recognition-with-you-own-keras-model/).

Comment: @Oxbowerce Thank you for your advice! I've edited my question and is it a correct understanding?

Comment: Putting the code there would give an error since the `samples` variable is not defined. Have a look at the original blogpost you linked as there is a code block that shows you exactly what the order of the different lines should be.

Comment: @Oxbowerce Thank you for your reply. Actually, the `samples` variable was not defined outside of the `load_data`  function on the original code.

Comment: It is though, on the first code block in section two you see `samples` is defined after the `load_data` function as follows: `samples = train_samples + val_samples`.

Comment: Could you write your answer on the answer form? Then I'll close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of classes is something you have to define yourself depending on the problem you're working with. In the blogpost you've linked you see that they refer to a variable called `schema`, which is defined in in the previous blogpost to the one you've linked as follows: `schema = ['_'] + sorted({tag for sentence in samples for _, tag in sentence})`. This also refers to a variable called `samples`, which is defined as `samples = train_samples + val_samples`. Combining these pieces of code the correct preprocessing pipeline would be as follows:

```
def load_data(filename: str):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        lines = [line[:-1].split() for line in file]
    samples, start = [], 0
    for end, parts in enumerate(lines):
        if not parts:
            sample = [(token, tag.split('-')[-1]) 
                        for token, tag in lines[start:end]]
            samples.append(sample)
            start = end + 1
    if start < end:
        samples.append(lines[start:end])
    return samples

train_samples = load_data('data/01_raw/bag.conll')
val_samples = load_data('data/01_raw/bgh.conll')
samples = train_samples + val_samples
schema = ['_'] + sorted({tag for sentence in samples for _, tag in sentence})
```

Comment: @Oxbwerce Thank you for your answer. [This](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/99755/an-issue-for-sub-word-tokenization-preprocessing-transformer) is a related question, I'd appreciate if you could check this one in your spare time.